Conformality of analogues of rotation and reflection in an annulus
Let $A_{1,r} = \{ 1 < |z| < r \}$ where $2 <r$.
I want to know if there exists a Jordan arc contained in the above annulus, $\gamma$ which starts at $1$, and next passes through $2$, and then passes through $2  \exp(i \frac{\pi}{4})$, and eventually reaches the boundary of the annulus , whose rotates $\exp(i \psi) \gamma$ partition the annulus $A_{1,r}$, i.e any two rotates are disjoint, such that the mapping $\exp(i (\psi)) \gamma(t) \rightarrow \exp(-i \psi) \gamma(t)$ is conformal in the sense that it preserves the magnitude of angles locally (and need not preserve the sign of these angles), at every point besides on $\gamma$, and such that the mapping extends to a homeomorphism of the annulus to itself.
Discussion in the comments
It has been clarified in the comments that if $\gamma$ is regular enough, then such an extension must be a reflection so that $\gamma$ must have constant argument because it is fixed pointwise by the extension. Therefore any such Jordan arc $\gamma$ must be something which is not piecewise $C^1$ and may need to have cusps.
In other terms my overarching question is, is it possible that for some arcs $\gamma$ of the form described above, there could be conformal mapping of the annulus minus that arc to itself which extends to a homeomorphism of the annulus to itself fixing the arc point wise, but which is not a conformal map at some points of the arc. If such arcs of the form described above do exist then I want to know if for these arcs the mapping I defined above could be conformal on the annulus minus the arc.

It seems that your $f_2$ fixes the curve $L$ pointwise.  If a conformal or anticonformal map fixes such a piecewise-linear curve pointwise, then it is either identity or a reflection, and in the latter case the curve is a line segment.

@MoisheKohan Thanks for your comment. I agree, in which case my $f_2$ can’t be conformal. I know that for any such curve $\gamma$ which is removable for quasiconformality, the map defined in my second edit cannot be anything but a reflection, which means my curve $L$ must have constant argument (it is a radial ray). I am wondering if it is possible though, to have an arc $\gamma$ like the one I describe in my second edit, which is not a quasi arc (so has a cusp), for which such a map might be conformal. It seems unlikely but I can’t discount it using the removability result.

Every anti-conformal self-map of an annulus is a reflection, hence, cannot fix any arc unless it is a line segment. As for fixed-point sets of anticonformal maps between different domains in the complex plane, I am not sure. They can be real-analytic curves, but singularities of such curves are unclear to me (i.e. if these can be cuspidal).

I meant conformal maps of an annulus minus an arc connecting the boundary circles to the same annulus minus that arc, if such a map had extended to a homeomorphism of the annulus (which may or may not fix every point of the arc), is it always true that this extension is conformal also at points of the arc? This is true if the arc is sufficiently nice, and the strongest condition I know which guarantees the extension is conformal is if the arc is the image of a line segment by a Quasiconformal map of the plane. Piecewise linear arcs are examples of quasi arcs, but arcs with cusps are not.

So I was asking if it is always true that such conformal maps extend to be conformal mappings of the whole annulus to itself, which would make them reflections or the identity.

I now find your question very unclear.

@MoisheKohan I have edited the question to try and emphasize the underlying question I should have asked from the beginning. Thank you for helping me clarify things.
